# Send Post data all as one packet in Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, post, tcp

I have an issue whereby my Arduino only likes receiving one complete packet for POST data. However my browser and other forms are sending this separated out, header and data separately with reassembly packets also.

This is the code:

```
           $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           crossDomain: true,
           url: "http://192.168.1.177/",
           data: message,
           dataType: "text",
           contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
         });
```

Is there any way to force that it is sent as one packet or even doing this as a raw TCP packet? I've tried several methods to no avail.

Comment: have you considered GET instead of POST. I found this informative: https://blog.josephscott.org/2009/08/27/xmlhttprequest-xhr-uses-multiple-packets-for-http-post/ . Apparently it also depends of your browser. FF should do one packet if your payload isn't too heavy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I tried many variations and found all to do the same. I do understand FF to do one packet but want a consistent approach across browsers.